# commons collections Buffer capacity

Tags: java, apache-commons

I don't see a way to get the maximum capacity of a bounded buffer in apache's commons?  Specifically, I'm using [BoundedFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/BoundedFifoBuffer.html).  How do you query it for it's capacity??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the size to the constructor. If you do not specify the size, it is 32.

A quick glance at a source code suggests there is no limit to how large the specified size can be (other than the limit on an `int` having to be `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31-1`). The only check in the constructor is for the size to be `> 0`.
There is also the practical limit of the amount of free memory you can allocate.

It's not clear why, but there really is no method for querying the capacity of the buffer. (Presumably if you're adding elements ignorantly of the capacity you should catch `BufferOverflowException` to detect when you've reached the capacity.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only specify the size of it on object construction.